# How can I restore proper function of the tab key and traverse all form inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm building an interactive speed calculator and I want desktop browser users to be able to navigate and provide inputs using the keyboard alone if they wish.

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/mannadu/pen/EBNmzz

I tried to accomplish this using the tabindex="0" property on all form inputs, as well as on list items which allow the user to choose from among a few popular running event distances.

Tabbing across the form works fine If I tab through the elements without making a selection, but the tab key stops working as soon as I choose a value from among the popup options for the "Distance" input.

Any suggestions as to what is wrong with the code, and what needs to change to restore expected behavior of the tab-key after entering the first input value?

Relevant portion of the html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div class="form-group center-content distance-input">
  <label class="col-form-label" for="race-distance">
    <input size="10" type="text" tabindex="0" id="race-distance" v-model:value="input_distance" class="btn btn-outline-light form-control-lg-border border-light" on:blur="modalTrackEvent" v-on:focus="modalTrackEvent" rows="1" v-on:change="modalTrackEvent" v-on:keyup="modalTrackEvent" placeholder="Distance" />
  </label>
  <!--CHANGE DISTANCE UNITS -->
  <!--COMMON RACE LENGTHS -->
  <div class="event-modal track-evt-list" v-bind:class="[ismodalvisible ? 'observable' : 'invis']" tabindex="0">
    <ul>
      <li class="btn btn-outline-light" v-bind:class="[ismodalvisible ? 'observable' : 'invis']" v-on:keyup.enter="setInputDist" v-on:mousedown="setInputDist"  v-for="(trackevt, idx) in trackevent" v-bind:key="idx" v-bind:raceid="idx" tabindex="0">{{ trackevt.id }} {{ trackevt.label }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The tab keys are still working. It's just that because you used CSS `opacity` to hide the elements by using `opacity: 0` in your `invis` class (and `opacity: 1` in the `observed` class), the tab key will cycle through all those "hidden" buttons (they are still there, just transparent) as well. Just keep hitting the tab key and you will see the cursors appearing eventually.

If you use [the visibility property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) and replace `opacity: 1` with `visibility: visible`, `opacity: 0` with `visibility: hidden` in your CSS it should work as expected. (Elements with `visibility: hidden` will not be part of the tab key cycle.)

A working CodePen example [can be seen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bPBzyr).

Comment: Okay I see! visibility works just great, I didnt realize it would work just like opacity  with css transitions, but it much better represents the desired effect. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Even if visibility doesn't work in transitions, I think you can put them both in your CSS.